# Get variable from eachfeature function to php?

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I have get the variable from onEachFeature function and set on a HTML tag, like this

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.TenCty); 
  layer.on("click", function(e)
  {
    var popup = e.target.getPopup();
    var content = popup.getContent();
    document.getElementById('test').textContent = content;
   } 
};
```

This is my PHP

```
<body>
        <h2>My Map</h2>
        <p id="test"></p>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script src="js/new.js"> </script>
</body>
```

I have get the value to show on HTML but I want the variable to get to PHP? Exactly is the content from popup (`content` variable) to echo to PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have an HTML textbox and you want to place the clicked features attribute into the textbox. Here I get the textbox, then set the value.

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {          
   layer.on('click', function (e) {     

     var a = document.getElementById("test");
    a.innerHTML=e.target.feature.properties.TenCty);
```

Comment: No, I mean, I want the value from this "e.target.feature.properties.TenCty", to pass to PHP variable. Anyway, thanks very much. Actually, I have read about ajax to send variable to PHP, but I don't know why it didn't work

Comment: Actually, your answer helps me very much, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So you know how to get the value from a click, then pass it to a function that uses AJAX to send it to your PHP page.

In JavaScript

```
passToPHP("e.target.feature.properties.TenCty);


function passToPHP(myVariable){

    var dataString = 'var1=' + myVariable 

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "UpData.php",  //my PHP page
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
        success: function() {
            console.log("Data sent by POST");
        }
    });
}
```

In PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['var1'])) {
    $thePassedVariable = $_POST['var1'];
}
```